# Seeking Recommendations for Lightweight Libraries for Strongly Typed TypeScript RESTful API Endpoints

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, http, type-safety

I am currently exploring lightweight options for constructing strongly typed TypeScript RESTful API endpoints in a Node API service and am interested to know what libraries or tools the community recommends for this purpose.

#### Core Requirements:

- The ability to add type checks.
- Minimizing the time spent on input validation and error handling.

#### Options Explored:

I have come across a couple of libraries, but they haven’t been updated in a while:

1. [zod-endpoints](https://github.com/flock-community/zod-endpoints)
2. [typepoint](https://github.com/typepoint/typepoint)

Additionally, I have considered using a combination of [Simplify](https://github.com/SimplifyJs/Simplify) and the [TypeScript generator from OpenAPI](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript/). However, this seems like it might be a more maintenance-heavy option.

#### Questions:

1. Does anyone have experience with the above libraries/tools, and if so, what are your thoughts on them?
2. Are there any alternative libraries or tools that you have found to be effective for creating strongly typed TypeScript RESTful API endpoints?
3. Is there a preferred library or tool that strikes a balance between being lightweight and maintaining strong types?

Thank you in advance for your insights and recommendations! I’m keen to learn from your experiences and to discover what the community finds effective for this use case.